# Duda con campo de tipo fecha de SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

¿Existe alguna manera de conocer en qué formato mostrará la fecha en el navegador  un campo de tipo Fecha de SharePoint?

Esto independientemente de como se tenga configurado el sistema para mostrar la fecha.

quiero devolver a ese campo la fecha en formato correcto, ya que una fecha como 06/02/2017 me la puede mostrar como 02/06/2017 si es que no conozco de que manera me mostrará esta misma.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Que tal @mslash, encontre esto en el foro de Microsoft, espero te sriva.
[https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/5297e2fb-215e-475f-a702-9c42096fddea/unificar-formato-de-fecha-en-sharepoint-2010?forum=mosses]

Comment: Mucas gracias Julio por tu respuesta, me parece que en el foro de Microsoft lo enfocan más para trabajarlo dentro de los Workflows con SharePoint Designer, pero me gustaría saber (del lado cliente) como lo va a pintar en la pagina web, para posteriormente yo pasarle el valor en ese mismo formato

Answer (score 0):

Una vez que configuras el tipo de formato de fecha en la pagina de SharePoint esta no cambia independientemente de que navegador utilices

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Con momment js puedes formatear la fecha.

moment().format('dddd');

[Momment JS](https://momentjs.com/)